# nx angular monorepo, tailwind not applying styles to lib components, only app components

Tags: angular, nomachine-nx

As the title says, i am having issues with installing tailwindcss globally, to be specific in my libraries and am finding it difficcult to get my library components to contain tailwindcss styles.

This is a very bare bones application with an app and 1 library purely to get tailwind working.

If i use any component in common-ui e.g navigation, there is no styling applied but there is styling applied to the components that live inside of the app folder e.g alan-george-poc. Any ideas, thank you?

[image: file structure]